# Highlight already visited questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-interface

i'd like to have the questions i already visited to be highlighted so it would be easier to scroll thorugh them espcially when new ones are arriving.

how about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My browsers perfectly show the links I've visited, and I did not do anything fancy for that.

(Maybe you should set your browser to keep a longer history?)

Comment: yeah, mine too (just saw it) but it's not obvious enough for me

Comment: @Arjan I work on multiple machines, including a smart phone. Those are different browsers, and I would *very* much like an indication that I've visited before.

Comment: Very good point, @owlstead. And though some browsers allow for synchronising these things on different machines, at work I do use my own SE account, but use my work address to login to my browsers. Still then, I guess this was not what the question was about, back in 2009? Maybe a new feature request for *"Synchronise and highlight visited questions on multiple browsers/devices"*?

Comment: (Or: *"across browsers/devices"*.)

Comment: @owlstead, related: [Add a “recently viewed” tab in the user account page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page), but it seems that [Nicks's answer there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page/116315#116315) is not giving you much hope.

Comment: @Arjan I think that was exactly what I was looking for, I've asked Nick to see if something similar is possible (explicit ignore for a month or so).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Greasemonkey or Stylish to change the a:visited links to something much more obnoxious if you like.  I'm sure someone will come along with a script soon enough ;)

Comment: I think that requiring to install a plugin to get this functionality is a bit much, especially when there are multiple browsers involved (and in my case I cannot just install more plugins at my company).