# Add a "recently viewed" tab in the user account page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page

I'd like to see a list of questions that I've recently viewed. This might go on the user page (but only for the user - not for all to see).

- This *would* be different from favorites, as it would only be recently viewed.
- This would *not* be redundant with browser history, as it would persist across computers (so I can see at home what I was looking at from work).
- This would *not* be redundant with recent activity, since I may not have had any activity on a question I recently viewed.

Any takers?

Perhaps show recently viewed questions where the `Related` links currently are, and slide everything else down?

Comment: I'd like to bump this rather than add a new request. I think this would be useful as I'm currently trying to find a question on MSO that I read a few days ago, but didn't answer, favourite or comment on it and would be a good way to "follow up" threads of interest.

Comment: This would be good.. it could be modeled after reddit.

Comment: +1. I often find myself browsing StackOverflow trying to solve a problem, finding people with the same problem but without a solution, and then manually solving the problem myself. It'd be great if I could easily get back to the question and provide them with my solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate in the other direction @Mark as this has an official answer.

Comment: @ben It looks like enough others have gone with the chronological first question, but I'm bothering to complete this comment because I just realised you've just used UEQ and not some special Unicode inversion :-)

Answer (score 20):

This would involve tracking a *tremendous* amount of data on the site databases, a transcriptional load that has no comparison currently.  While we log every HTTP request so we can see and continually improve performance we do so in an external database on a dedicated server with bulk inserts...that's simply not doable on production SO without causing a lot of write contention, even on SSDs, we simply handle a *lot* of traffic.

To get an idea, in the last 30 days the Stack Exchange network has handled:

- **332,719,349** page views
- **1,134,798,441** total requests

*Can* we do this?  Yeah absolutely, we can figure something out, probably a culled list in redis would be the only *reasonable* approach performance-wise.  The question is can this significant increase in per-view transactional data be justified?  I don't think it can be, not for the small number of people who would notice/use the feature.

Comment: I guess this also answers [Is there a way to see how many questions you have read?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115896/is-there-a-way-to-see-how-many-questions-you-have-read), right?

Comment: Any figures on what part of those views/requests were made by authenticated users? Like the Ajax calls to get one's personal votes for the posts on a page. (Even a small percentage would still be a large number, I guess, so making those database selects to become inserts is still too much, I guess.)

Comment: What about a more moderate version, where a user explicitly can disregard a question for say, about a month. Would that be feasible? There are a huge load of questions that I see multiple times whereas I definitely did not want to see them again.

Comment: Nick, what if you only listed the most recent n pages instead? Even just the most recent 5? It would still be a useful addition even if limited. I guess it could also become a feature for those with a reputation or something (as part of the reward scheme) so you're not using databases for new visitors who will probably never use the site more than once?

Comment: Nick, is this still true since http://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data [has been made available](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270896/is-so-monitoring-its-users-and-adapting-ads-based-on-that/270969#270969), which includes `QuestionViews`?

Answer (score 18):

Surely you could implement this as a client side feature, saving the 'viewed questions' as in html5 storage or in a series of cookies?

Obviously this wouldn't be portable across machines and would have some technical complexities (binding views to particular user accounts say).

...but in general, I find that the only time I'm interested in a previously viewed question is during the same session, when I've accidentally closed a window with a bindingly awesome solution to *exactly the problem I'm having* ...and then, when I search for it, I can't find it again.

Even if this was only a per-session feature, it'd be truely awesome.

(also, if you want to save your session's views, you could totally have an export-as-bookmarklet option).

I realize that your browser *should* be able to generate this information for you, but both firefox and chrome get so confused by the fact that I visit stackoverflow so much that they list dozens of irrelevant urls that isn't any more helpful than just searching.

The feature I really want is: Where the heck is that question I *was just looking at 2 minutes ago*?

--

Edit: I notice the original question specifically said they wanted it to persist across different machines. Perhaps this isn't the best solution for that specifically.

Comment: +1 Almost just wrote this same post.

Comment: Funnily enough, the SE mobile app does exactly this, keeping a locally stored history for browsing.

Answer (score 3):

A good alternative to this would be an option to view questions you voted on recently (obviously where only you could view them).  This resolves [Nick's concern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116315/143965) about tracking all the data because votes are already tracked.  If you think you might want to come back to a question/answer, vote it up or down.  Or possibly up-vote a comment and the vote log could show that.

Comment: This is (now) available in activity in one's profile. One cannot search those though, and would need to browse through many pages of votes (if one votes often).