# How does Stack Overflow keep statistics on questions, votes, views, and answers?

Tags: discussion

How does Stack Overflow keep track of the number of questions under a tag as well as the number of votes, views, answers per question, etc? I'm just eager to know if they maintain a separate table or do a count query every time.

Comment: Take a look at an open source alternative: http://www.osqa.net/ check their database schema.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a duplicate, but a fellow MSO user posted an interesting writeup about this at [Dissecting the Stack Overflow views counter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter). Excerpt:

> From what I can tell there is now a JavaScript section in each answer page (used to be CSS in 2008):
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="/posts/3590653/ivc/a947"></script>
> <noscript>
>     <div><img src="/posts/3590653/ivc/a947" class="dno" alt=""></div>
> </noscript>
> ```
>
> The last part of the URL - **a947** - seems to be dynamically generated. It is changed every 15-20 minutes and is **the same for all questions and presumably users** (I tried anonymous access, changing my IP address, it stays the same during the interval).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a database of questions and answer.

Each user has a unique ID to query on.