# Is there a way to see how many questions you have read?

Tags: support

Having looked for something in my browser history last night I noticed I visit an average of about 200 webpages per day and I was wondering how many of these are SO. Any way to find out the total number of questions I have viewed (either total or unique)?

Comment: [Some say](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter) the hidden view counter is not related to one's account. But if the visits are recorded, then it would be nice to show that! Like *"You've visited this page ... times, first time on ..."*

Comment: This seems like it would be a pretty expensive thing to track...I know I look at a few hundred SO pages per day and I'm less active than many others.

Comment: You can get a pretty good idea from your per-site browser history.

Comment: If in doubt, *too freaking many*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a "recently viewed" tab in the user account page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such thing is not tracked on the servers as far as I know. I strongly believe they just have counter **how many** people visited particular question, but not **who** visited.

That said, you'll have to resort to your browser.. Chrome allows you to search your history so here is a shortcut to display all *stackoverflow.com* pages you visited:
chrome://history/#q=stackoverflow.com&p=0

Comment: I guess this is confirmed by Nick's statement about *not* tracking individual page views in [Add a “recently viewed” tab in the user account page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page/116315#116315).

Comment: Yes indeed.. thanks for pointing this out! :)