# Closing an edit review makes it disappear

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits

I recently accidentally closed an edit review window without taking any action on it. Since I *wanted* to take action (I was using another browser tab to confirm details in the edit) it was frustrating to have it disappear from the edit queue.

Using the browser "back" button didn't help, as that dynamically reloaded the page, showing nothing needing editing. Moreover my "recent actions" list did not show that as an action (isn't skipping an edit an action?).

The major problem here was that I didn't have any easy way of finding the post in question, so I could click the "Edit" link. Finally I found it in the browser history.

I suggest a way of seeing a list of recent suggested edits, that you may have skipped but are still active, and thus you are still entitled to take action on the suggested edit.

---

*(edit)*

Just tested again with a recent "low quality post". I closed the browser tab, and the post dropped out of my review queue. It also did not appear as a "skipped" edit. So it looks like the server has noted I looked at it, and as I did not take any **direct** action (like clicking the Skip button) it has silently removed it from my review queue. Now I can't find it unless I dig it up on my browser history.

Comment: In my experience, reviews you simply *closed* will reappear in the usual queue flow once your lock expires, which takes 5 minutes. (Assuming no one else has the lock.)

Comment: Thanks for that comment. The post I closed before has now reappeared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I recently accidentally closed an edit review window without taking any action on it. Since I wanted to take action (I was using another browser tab to confirm details in the edit) it was frustrating to have it disappear from the edit queue.

I can understand how this would be frustrating. As far as I know the only time SE saves a draft is like when you have started writing a question or answer, but it only saves it a draft for like 1 or 2 posts per site.

There are no drafts that are saved for editing posts whether in the review queues or on the actual posts. Most suggested edits that need to be improved by editing in the review queue normally don't take too long. Also, there are usually many different people doing reviews so they get handled pretty quickly.

As you've tested, this happens in any queue where if you close out the window/tab of the review you were given, you won't be able to go back in the queue and review it ***unless*** you have a direct link to that review (and of course the review still hasn't been completed by other users).

Now, if you'd want a list of links to recent reviews that have been given to you, I'd say they could do that, but I doubt they will since they have denied previous related requests, like [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page). Or maybe you'd be fine with just not removing unacted upon reviews from the queue if they are still active? I don't think that'd be too hard to implement, but don't think it'd be very worthwhile to implement it for reasons below.

I think most people have had something similar happen to them. In this case, I don't think it's worth developer time to create this feature since it's a pretty rare occurrence for most users and because reviews usually get completed quickly, there's not much real point in having this feature.

So what can you do? Be extra careful when spending any long amount of time editing a post as to not close the window. Go/search for that post using the search feature or google search. Edit that post directly instead of inside the queue.

> I suggest a way of seeing a list of recent suggested edits, that you may have skipped but are still active, and thus you are still entitled to take action on the suggested edit.

You can already view reviews you have skipped.

**Click on Review**
**Click on recent reviews** (of the queue you want to see recent reviews of)

[image]

**Click on history**

[image]

**Scroll down and click on show skipped reviews**

Now you will see a list of your reviews in that queue. If you don't already have the checkbox at the bottom selected (show skipped reviews) then checkmark it to see your skipped reviews as well.

[image]

<sup>*I was trying to draw a down arrow in the pic but it started looking more like a flower so I finished it off*</sup>

Comment: Note: If he didn't explicitly click the Skip button then it won't show up there.

Comment: Right. Also please note that feature-requests to show which questions you have viewed before have already been asked and declined https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page I'm not sure if anyone has asked to be able to view recent reviews that you have been given and didn't take action on, but  I would think that would be declined as well.

Comment: Thanks, but one more step in your list. After "Click on history" then click on "**My** review history" at the bottom of the list, and **then** you see "show skipped reviews". No wonder I didn't find that the first time. If you watch what you are doing with the mouse you are jumping from the top of the page, to near the bottom, back to near the top, then down to the bottom again. There must be an easier way, like: *Show all edits you can still review* (on the first page). Nice flower, BTW.

Comment: @NickGammon I didn't need to click on "my review history" to see my reviews or the show skipped reviews option. Wonder if that is a bug in that you needed to click on my review history first? Not sure what's goin on there.

Comment: I just did it again, more slowly. I definitely need that extra step. Maybe my site (Arduino beta) is coded slightly differently, or something. `I'm not sure if anyone has asked to be able to view recent reviews that you have been given and didn't take action on` - me neither, however it seems a reasonable thing to do. You skip an edit (or maybe walk away and close the window) and then regret it. I don't really want it to keep a history, just a way of showing edits, still pending, that I can contribute to.

Comment: See amended question. If you close the tab without taking action it does not count as skipped or anything else. It just disappears. (As @animuson said).

Comment: @NickGammon Right, like animuson stated in first comment, you have to actually take action by clicking "skip" for it to appear there (or another action like approve/edit/etc). Closing the window does not count as skip. So if you are feature-requesting something different I'd recommend not using the word "skip" since skip is an action and means something in the review queues.

Comment: OK, I revised the question title. As my question said, I closed the window without taking any action. I would have thought this should then stay in my queue as something I had not acted upon, especially if "skip" appears to be something you have to consciously decide to do. So my feature request really is that "doing nothing" (eg. a power failure on my PC) should not remove things from my review queue.

Comment: Thanks for you revised and clearer reply. I just want to clarify that I *hadn't typed anything*. The issue was not with losing my typing. I was just saying that the edit review, which I was being offered to edit, disappeared from the queue by merely viewing it, without taking action. I don't want the developers to waste time trying to save what I typed (which was nothing). I was just pondering whether to accept or reject the edit. Perhaps is is a non-issue because as @NathanTuggy said, if I wait long enough, it re-appears in the queue (I think).